# 1=1 doesn't work on Oracle DB queries or just through CF?

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to build a query that runs against an Oracle database our group has read access to that pulls down results for insertion and modification in a local copy under our control.  I've got my query built but I've run into a small problem.  To return the results of my query, I can't use a BETWEEN because of the way the DB is indexed; using date ranges causes it to run too slow and the PK doesn't increment sequentially.  Instead, I have to loop through an array of values and match those to the PK.

Normally, for something like this against SQL server, I'd throw something like this at it:

```
AND ( 
    1=1
    <cfloop array="#orderHeaderNumArray#" index="i">
        OR TABLENAME.S_HEADER_NUMBER LIKE '#i#%' 
    </cfloop>
)
```

Every time I've tried a 1=1 against an Oracle query however, I always get a UTF-8 error.  In the past, I've just half-assed a solution by setting a known-non-existent value as a conditional, but I was wondering if #1 is this an Oracle limitation or a CF one and #2 if there was a better solution along the lines of an always true instead of an always false conditional.

Edit: Server is CF10, but I don't know what version of Oracle we're using.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but when I do something like you are attempting, I use 1=2.

Comment: your query is always going to return every row matching whatever your WHERE clause is. The OR's will provide nothing in this instance

Comment: @Dan I could use that, but to my understanding always true executes faster than always false, which is why it's my preference.

Comment: @Matt, I don't follow what you mean.  Multiple conditionals in a SQL query don't work without appropriate operators.

Comment: Oh OK, then I'll just modify my query to have ten-thousand conditionals so I get an exact match for every record I expect to return.

Comment: @KRC `1 = 1` means it will always return true, so `1=1 or header like 'head%'` will always return all the rows because 1 always equals 1 the `or` part of your conditional is irrelevant as that statement will always return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND ( 
  1=1
  <cfloop array="#orderHeaderNumArray#" index="i">
     OR TABLENAME.S_HEADER_NUMBER LIKE '#i#%' 
  </cfloop>
  )
```

Does not work in Oracle or ColdFusion. Consider

```
AND ( 
  1=0
  <cfloop array="#orderHeaderNumArray#" index="i">
     OR TABLENAME.S_HEADER_NUMBER LIKE '#i#%' 
  </cfloop>
  )
```

If you are really concerned about the performance of `1=0`

```
AND ( 
  <cfloop array="#orderHeaderNumArray#" index="i">
     <cfif i NEQ orderHeaderNumArray[1]> OR </cfif> TABLENAME.S_HEADER_NUMBER LIKE '#i#%' 
  </cfloop>
  )
```

Comment: +1 for your last option. I hate to see `1=1` in queries (or `1=0`). Just looks lazy to me.

Comment: I prefer 1=0 to performing conditional logic inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using 1 = 1 is less than ideal, but I think it's acceptable as long as you inclue a comment as to why it's there.

But, more to the point of the question - have you tried assigning the primary key to itself instead? i.e.

```
AND ( 
    id = id
    <cfloop array="#orderHeaderNumArray#" index="i">
        OR TABLENAME.S_HEADER_NUMBER LIKE '#i#%' 
    </cfloop>
)
```